# TextMesh Pro Area Type Feature like in Illustrator

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I was wondering if TextMesh Pro has plans for adding a feature similar to the Area Type feature from Illustrator pictured below, basically having the bounding box of the text object be a custom shape or dependent on something else? There is the option to make your text fit the geometry but that does not seem to be it.

[image]

If there are no plans in the near future to make this feature, is there a way for me to look into the specifics of TextMesh Pro and try to make it myself? As far as I've seen I'm able to access some (?) of the source after downloading them from the package manager, but I don't really have an overview of what works with what. My guess would be that I have to look at the parts of the code responsible for creating the yellow bounding box around text objects, but I'm not able to find where that is being done. Alternatively, I'm also looking for how text alignment is being done as my problem does not need an as sophisticated solution as area type objects, just a specific way of formatting the text.